# How do I create a div clickable, with rails in HAML

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, onclick, haml

i have problem with my rails code in HAML page.
I need my div becomes clickable and take me to a link rails

```
.header_btn
     #(link_to_ledger(current_ledger))
```

I know I should use JAVA but do not know how to do
sorry for my English

Answer (score 2):

use

```
= link_to '#url' do
  .header_btn
    Link
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use Javascript to invoke the "click" event:

```
$(".tester").on("click", function(){
    window.location = $(this).attr("href");
});

<div class="tester" href="http://google.com">
    Testing!
</div>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gj910vL8/1/)

--

```
#view
.header_btn{ href: "your_url"}

#JS
$(document).on("click", ".header_btn", function(){
   window.location = $(this).attr("href");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know `HAML` but why don't you just wrap the `div` in an anchor tag?

```
<a href="#">
   <div>Stuff</div>
</a>
```

If you want to use `jQuery` you can use it's `click` function: http://api.jquery.com/click/